# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable when calling from a function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the `reactome2py` package to analyse pathways by adapting the `Reference code`. Unlike the reference code, which only read one file, my code intends to apply the `reactome2py`'s `analysis` function for three files, `mrna`, `cna`, and `meth`.

Reference code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OufIYapCWirfLsudpg0fw1OxD7KTud2y?usp=sharing#scrollTo=e1q6oxLUKGGR
The portion of the code that's throwing the error:

```
for k, v in chain.from_iterable(cna_dict_items):
        cna_dd[k].extend(v)
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from operator import methodcaller
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
from reactome2py import analysis

directory = "./gbm_tcga/"

def genepath(cna_row_dict):
    cna_dd = defaultdict(list)

    cna_dict_items = map(methodcaller("items"), cna_row_dict)

    for k, v in chain.from_iterable(cna_dict_items):
        cna_dd[k].extend(v)

    cna_dict = dict(cna_dd)

    return cna_dict


class DataProcessing:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t", header=0)

    def data_dict(self):
        df_dict = self.df.to_dict("records")
        return df_dict

def main():
    cna = DataProcessing(directory + "data_linear_cna.txt")

    cna_dict = cna.data_dict()

    gene_path = genepath(cna_dict)



main()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 41, in main
    gene_path = genepath(cna_dict)
  File "main.py", line 19, in genepath
    cna_dd[k].extend(v)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: you call it a `dict` but you pass in instances of your `DataProcessing` class, which is not iterable by default.

Comment: @rcshon what is the solution?

Comment: you defined `split_data` and `pca` but you never call them. I'd assume you you wanted to call `split_data` first to get your dictionaries before passing them into `genepath2dict`

Comment: @rcshon I edited the question by removing the `split_data` function and replace it with `data_dict`, and then call it in `main`. I still get the same error.

Comment: I mean it throws an error on another line (a float).

Comment: you seem to be missing the line `df = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split(","), axis=0)` from the reference code. Is it possible this is leading to a malformed dictionary? Maybe try printing your data dictionary and the reference dictionary to check that they have the same structure.